# Transaction issuer identity information in Corda contract code

Tags: corda

How to get information about the party that started transaction in contract code (verify)? That would be useful for implement checks like "only owner of the input state can do some action" in contract instead of flow.

Thanks. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not contained in a Corda transaction, and therefore cannot be checked by the `verify` method.

Instead, you should make the owner of the state a required signer, and they should only sign if they are willing to authorise the transfer.

Additionally, you may want to put a check like the following in your flow to prevent human error:

```
check(ourIdentity == lenderIdentity) {
    "Obligation transfer can only be initiated by the lender."
}
```